# ¿Por qué no se ve mi imagen en botón?

Tags: javascript, html

Utilizo Sublime Text y verán: estaba haciendo un ejemplo sobre JavaScript dentro de HTML y pues puse las imagenes mediante una ruta local; mi problema es que en la etiqueta `<button>` no presenta cambio al presionar el botón. ¿A qué se debe esto?
Les dejo aquí el código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Segundo ejercicio</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>¿Que puede hacer JavaScript?</h2>

<p>JavaScript puede cambiar los valores de los atributos de HTML</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='C:\Users\LostTx\Downloads\FocoOn.png'">"Encender la luz"</button>

<img id="myImage" src="C:\Users\LostTx\Downloads\FocoOff.png" style="width: 100px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código lo he copiado tal cual y pegado en un .html cualquiera y funciona perfectamente. Aunque tu código parece estar bien, el que pones de ejemplo para poder ejecutar tiene mal la ruta -> file:///C:/UsersLostTxDownloadsFocoOn.png faltan las barras, esto lo verificas con la consola desde desarrollador de chrome o firefox.

He copiado tu código tal cual solo he cambiado las rutas de las fotos y en vez de estar en local están en internet para evitar fallos y que puedas visualizarlo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Segundo ejercicio</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>¿Que puede hacer JavaScript?</h2>

<p>JavaScript puede cambiar los valores de los atributos de HTML</p>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0df83637c1842402ebb7a7a57bc7a584?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'">"Encender la luz"</button>

<img id="myImage" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gh987HHEvNg8X84QhyT9bboGLZrCHY6uTNSJFL9RSg=k-s32" style="width: 100px;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si me sirvio ahora puedo visualizar la imagen, Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Traivex, si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.